# Login stops working after changing the input field name "email" to "login-email"

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am developing a Laravel 6.6.2 project and I came across this problem I can't seem to fix.

In the file login.blade.php view i'm trying to change `name="email"` in the input fields to `name="login-email"`. But when I do this the login doesn't work anymore. So I think that Laravel uses the name email somewhere to validate the login. I can't find where Laravel looks for the name `email` instead of `login-email` and if this even is needed to change?

The reason I need to change this is because javascripts use the name value too. (Because I brought a template). I am still learning Laravel so don't be to harsh. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: of course it doesn't work any more, check the traits in the Login controller and you will see that you can set the method to get the "email" field by overriding a method in a trait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has excellent documentation.  This is always a good place to start.

**# Authenticating**
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-authenticating

> **Username Customization**
>   By default, Laravel uses the `email` field for authentication. If you would like to customize this, you may define a `username` method on your `LoginController`:

In your case, you would return `login-email` from the username method.

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'login-email';
}
```

Of course, you will also need to add or rename this field in the database if you haven't already.

---

Alternatively to renaming the field in the database, you could override the `credentials` method.

```php
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'email' => $request->{$this->username()},
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}
```

Comment: you don't have to adjust the name of the field in the database, you can override the `credentials` method if it isn't the same name in the database

Comment: so in my credentials override in the login controller I need to put something like this?: `return $request->only('login-email', 'password');` @lagbox

Comment: you only need to override that method if the field in your database you want to use isn't the one you set in the `username` method ... it already uses the field you set in the `username` method for the credentials

Comment: @lagbox Please feel free to add any edits if you feel you can expand upon this better.  Or you are welcome to provide a new answer.  It won't hurt my feelings.

Comment: i was just responding to the OP but  your last edit you had would be what they would need to do if the form field and database field weren't the same :)

Comment: Not a problem.  You just sounded like you are more versed in this particular area than myself and I didn't want to give the wrong information.  I've restored the last edit you referenced.